# XCTestAssertNil crash due to "nil" parameter

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xctest

I'm using XCTest to write unit tests in my project, and when using the `XCAssertNil()` or `XCAssertNotNil()` methods, XCTest framework crashes.

Here's my test:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(messageCollection.fieldName, "field_name must be not-nil")
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
2015-06-22 17:05:17.629 xctest[745:8747] *** Assertion failure in void _XCTFailureHandler(XCTestCase *, BOOL, const char *, NSUInteger, NSString *, NSString *, ...)(), /SourceCache/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-7701/XCTestFramework/OtherSources/XCTestAssertionsImpl.m:41
Test Case '-[Wakanda_iOS_Framework_Tests.WAKAdapterTest testEntityCollectionParsing]' started.
2015-06-22 17:05:17.631 xctest[745:8747] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Parameter "test" must not be nil.'
```

**It seems that XCTest has a parameter named *test* which cannot be nil**, strange for a method expected to check for nil (or non-nil) values... Does anyone else got this problem and solved it?

Comment: I had this same error but for a different situation.  I _think_ the problem was that I was subtly misusing the test API -- doing async tests, and trying to use `XCTAssertEqual` *after* calling `expectation.fulfill()`.  My guess is that the test framework doesn't notice the real problem, and then crashes later for a seemingly unrelated reason.

Comment: Yes - when you call `expectation.fulfill()` and then order some async code the `XCTestCase` might get unloaded. Check my answer below @MattFenwick

Comment: Yesterday, I had the same  "exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Parameter "test" must not be nil.'" error using the XCAssertNotNil() and XCAssertTrue() functions. Strange thing was, these tests had been in use for weeks, but when I changed one of the parameters in the function I had been testing, it started. And it was a showstopper, too: none of the tests after the exception would run. I finally solved the problem by doing a Clean on the project, throwing out the folder in DerivedData and restarting the computer. Xcode 9.2, btw.

Answer (score 6):

According to this rdar http://www.openradar.me/22409527, this seems to be a bug in XCTest, leading to a crash when you check an optional that is nil.

You can fix your test with:

```
XCTAssert(messageCollection.fieldName != nil, "field_name must be not-nil")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, I still get the same error. I'm using Xcode 8 though.

Comment: @MatthewDrill What version of Xcode are you using exactly? Just tested in Xcode 8.2.1 and the XCTAssertNotNil() works as expected now, at least for me.  
`var optional: String?`  
`XCTAssertNotNil(optional, "field_name must be not-nil")`

Answer (score 6):

As I see in XCTestAssertionsImpl.h:

```
XCT_EXPORT void _XCTFailureHandler(XCTestCase *test, BOOL expected, const char *filePath, NSUInteger lineNumber, NSString *condition, NSString * __nullable format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(6,7);
```

It's first argument - `test` - refers to the instance of `XCTestCase`. So the message might be: "**Hey man, your `XCTestCase` object doesn't exist any more, so I cannot invoke any method on it**".

It might be a case for example when you call some `XCTAssert...` in asynchronous block, that might be invoked long after your enclosing `XCTestCase` object has gone.

If that might be a case adding `[unowned self]` to your async block wont solve the issue here, you need to go for Expectations or synchronise your code.

Answer (score 4):

Since your "test" is nil, I'm guessing you're trying to call `XCAssertNil` from a standalone function you wrote as a helper. The XCTest assertions take `self` as "test", so they can't be in standalone functions. They must be in methods. Try changing your helper function to a method.

Comment: Actually I'm already in a test method, and my other test functions such as `XCTAssertEqual` are working correctly...

Comment: Weird. Try moving an XCTAssertEqual around in your test method. Does it work next to the XCTAssertNil?

Comment: I did't even noticed how I cut code into helper function with XCTAsserts and that was the reason of my crushes! Thank you @JonReid

Answer (score 1):

Same error occured in a similar situation like this:

```
let expectation = self.expectation(description: "exp")

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    expectation.fulfill()
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
    XCTAssert(false)
}

waitForExpectations(timeout: 2, handler: nil)
```

So calling `XCTAssert` after the expectation was fulfilled.
Which ofcourse is wrong.

Comment: Same issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error when the test function finished to execute but than if you have anything async that call any XCTAssert. It will crash your test. I had the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an Asynch you need to use a expectation:

```
//PRIOR TO TEST<br>
let validation = expectation(description: "FullFill")
<br><br>
//AFTER ASYNCH IS COMPLETED<br>
validation.fulfill()

//BOTTOM OF YOUR TEST<br>
self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10){ error in }
```